# append the element to last of the current label

Tags: jquery

I have multiple divs like this:

```
<div>
<label for="mobile">Mobile number:</label>
<input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile"  class="inputbox " value="1234"/>
</div>
```

Now I want to add a `<p>some text</p>` to the end of input by selecting label like this

```
$('label[for="mobile"]')
```

The result should be this:

```
<div>
<label for="mobile">Mobile number:</label>
<input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile"  class="inputbox " value="1234"/>
<p>some text</p>
</div>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('label[for="mobile"]').closest('div').append('<p>some text</p>');
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LgPwM/1/)

Comment: Are the labels different? do you want to insert the p element to every class that matches inputbox?

Comment: OP specify to select `$('label[for="mobile"]')` so the above will be used only for `label[for="mobile"]`

Comment: I agree. Oh he deleted his comment saying 'there are multiple div's' So I was really asking him.

Comment: @C-Link: then clarify how, and by what criteria, you want this to work. Help us to help you, don't make us guess at what you want.

Comment: You want to insert the p element after 2 or more of these inputs? Correct. If so what is common between these inputs? That is why I asked about class. If you target the ID, it should only target one element as ID's should be unique.

Comment: So, if I may be so bold, in what way does my own answer fail for you?

Comment: @C-Link What is **code for all labels but should select id..**?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
$('input[id]').each(function(i,e){
    $('<p />', {
        'text' : 'Paragraph following the ' + e.id + ' element.'
    }).insertAfter(this);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7mY27/).

To check that there is a `label` element corresponding to that `input`:

```
$('input[id]').each(function(i,e){
    if ($('label[for="' + e.id + '"]').length){
        $('<p />', {
            'text' : 'Paragraph following the ' + e.id + ' element.'
        }).insertAfter(this);
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7mY27/1/).

References:

- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$('div > input').after('<p>some text</p>');
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KEfaF/)**